# Generate all possible words from 2-D matrix - DP Approach

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have a N x N character matrix. Now I want to generate all possible words of different lengths. I don't have any dictionary, I want to generate all possible words from the 2-D matrix. Movement from any cell can be in all 8 directions from the cell - left, top, right, bottom and all diagonals.

I know using Depth First Search it can be easily coded but that approach is very slow as it explores all paths. I have written a piece of DP based program. But not able to generate all the words. Is it possible to generate the words using DP?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
//Testing a dp solution.
int[] dx = {0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
int[] dy = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1}; 

char[][] board = {{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F'}, {'I', 'J', 'K'}};

boolean[][][] dp = new boolean[2][board.length][board[0].length];

for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
        {
            if(k == 0)
            {
                dp[k][i][j] = true;
                continue;
            }

            for(int p = 0; p < dx.length; p++)
            {
                int x = i + dx[p];
                int y = j + dy[p];

                if(x >= 0 && x < board.length && y >= 0 && y < board[0].length)
                {
                    if(dp[k-1][x][y] == true)
                    {
                        System.out.print(board[x][y] + "" + board[i][j]);
                    }

                    System.out.print("   ");
                }
            }

            System.out.print("   ");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: You have to say what it means to "generate" a word in your question. I am assuming that you mean that a word can on any square and go either vertically, horizontally, or diagonally for any number of squares (like a word in a crossword puzzle), but perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, from any cell you can go to all of its 8-neighbors / 8 adjacent cells.

Comment: Kosre, this does not sound to me a like the best application of dynamic programming (DP). DP is a form of optimization approach where you are looking to find, efficiently globally optimal (minimal or maximal) solution as a path through a tabularly laid out problem knowing that sub-structures are optimal. Here you are maybe looking for a run-time optimization for a, as it appears to me, combinatorial problem.